# Too many parameters with EF6 mapped to stored procedures

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF6 alpha and using the new functionality to map to stored procedures. In my unit test I'm receiving the error "Procedure or function CreateDayDetail has too many arguments specified."

The SQL Profiler shows the following proc call:

```
exec [Schedule].[CreateDayDetail] @startTime=0,@duration=1,@durationEst=0,@isPaid=1,@requirePunch=0,@dayKey=16,@activityTypeKey=1,@TemplateDay_Key=NULL
```

The problem is the @TemplateDay_Key parameter which is being auto-generated. But, I'm not sure why it's being created when one isn't being created for ActivityType.

Here is the entity class:

```
public class DayDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Key { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TemplateDay Day { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ActivityType Activity { get; set; }

    [Range(TimeMinimum, TimeMaximum)]
    public int StartTime { get; set; }

    [Range(DurationMinimum, DurationMaximum)]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public bool DurationEstimated { get; set; }

    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }

    public bool RequirePunch { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the fluent API that I'm using to configure the model:

```
typeConfig.ToTable("Schedule.DayDetail");
typeConfig.Property(d => d.Key)
    .HasColumnName("DayDetailKey");
typeConfig.HasRequired(d => d.Day)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("TemplateDayKey"));
typeConfig.HasRequired(d => d.Activity)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("ActivityTypeKey"));

typeConfig.MapToStoredProcedures(sp =>
    sp.Insert(i => i.HasName("Schedule.CreateDayDetail")
        .Parameter(d => d.Day.Key, "dayKey")
        .Parameter(d => d.Activity.Key, "activityTypeKey")
        .Parameter(d => d.StartTime, "startTime")
        .Parameter(d => d.Duration, "duration")
        .Parameter(d => d.DurationEstimated, "durationEst")
        .Parameter(d => d.IsPaid, "isPaid")
        .Parameter(d => d.RequirePunch, "requirePunch"))
    .Update(u => u.HasName("Schedule.UpdateDayDetail")
        .Parameter(d => d.Key, "key")
        .Parameter(d => d.Day.Key, "dayKey")
        .Parameter(d => d.Activity.Key, "activityTypeKey")
        .Parameter(d => d.StartTime, "startTime")
        .Parameter(d => d.Duration, "duration")
        .Parameter(d => d.DurationEstimated, "durationEst")
        .Parameter(d => d.IsPaid, "isPaid")
        .Parameter(d => d.RequirePunch, "requirePunch")
        .Parameter(d => d.Version, "version"))
    .Delete(x => x.HasName("Schedule.DeleteDayDetail")
        .Parameter(d => d.Key, "key")
        .Parameter(d => d.Day.Key, "dayKey")
        .Parameter(d => d.Activity.Key, "activityTypeKey")
        .Parameter(d => d.Version, "version")));
```

I've looked at this for far too long today. I appreciate any help.......

Answer (score 0):

3 months old question...

It is there because you are using relationship without a foreign key in your model. You are creating relationship in your model not in your database.

You are not using: `.HasForeignKey(d => d.TemplateDayKey_ID);`

You are using `.Map(d => d.MapKey("TemplateDayKey"));` and this requires to pass this relation information to insert and update stored procedures as parameter to process this relation.

If you use ForeignKey based relationship in your model, you will see a parameter TemplateDayKey_id in stored procedures parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a property that is generated in the database on my model, and EF was trying to insert this property as a param because I didn't have the property properly marked up.  I needed to change

```
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

to

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

. . . and then EF stopped trying to insert that value as part of the proc.